# Have run laravel docker shift from 5.3 to 5.4 and 5.4 to 5.5 with problems

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, docker-compose, laravel-artisan

When running composer update it works until @php artisan package:discover
I then got:
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
Class 'Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider' not found
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

I got Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider class defined in app.php
[image]

So php artisan does not work at all. So what could be the problem?

Comment: Just remove the cache using `config:clear` command and then re-run the `composer dump-autoload` command. It seems like caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

The system has been upgraded to Laravel 9.20 so no problems anymore with upgrades.